# converting .prn file in to html page using java

Tags: java

how to convert .prn file in to html page using java.
I am treating it as a text file and reading it line by line but thats quite cumbersome as each line requires its own splitting logic. As prn file is nicely formatted can we directly extract the file and load it as an html?any suggessions?

Comment: Surround it with `<pre>` tags and call it a day?

Comment: Sorry.I cant understand .can you please provide more details?

Comment: I think that he is joking. Myself, I don't even know what `.prn` files are, or the steps you're using to "convert" them.

Comment: Only half in jest, I too don't know the structure of `.prn` files; but pre-formatted in html is preserved with `<pre>` tags. So `<pre>Some formatted text</pre>` will present the formatted text as is.

Answer (score 0):

Since a .prn file is byte stream that is sent to printer for printing, I think you are going to have to keep using your custom parser as it doesn't appear that the [Java Print Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jps/index.html) has any options for parsing.

If the tags are consistent with other file formats it may be worth while to check out other parsing libraries such as [simple.json](https://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and modify them to your needs.